# template pointer parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

Why a template function with a template parameter pack of pointers cannot be instantiated with offsets of the same pointer?

I mean: given this short code why must I comment out the last two lines?

```
template <int * ... pt> void f() {}

int n[] = {1, 2, 3};
int m = n[1];

int main()
{
    f<n>();  // this is accepted
    f<n, &m>();  // this is accepted too
    //f<n, n+1>(); // this is not.
    //f<n, &n[1]>(); // this isn't accepted neither
}
```

Doesn't `n+1` represent the same address as `&m` ? Or there is a difference in the linkage? Or what else?

Comment: `m` is its own variable; `&m` has no relation to `n`.

Comment: Try `int * p = &n[0]; f<p>();` for a nice explanation.

Answer (score 3):

See [cppreference.com - Template non-type arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments)

> - For pointers to objects, the template arguments have to designate the address of an object with static storage duration and a linkage (either internal or external), or a constant expression that evaluates to the appropriate null pointer or std::nullptr_t value.
>
> ...
>
> The only exceptions are that non-type template parameters of reference and pointer type cannot refer to/be the address of
>
> - a subobject (including non-static class member, base subobject, or array element);
> - a temporary object (including one created during reference initialization);

So the address of an array element is not allowed.

Comment: For reference, the quoted bit about subobjects (c++17-relevant) is derived from [this section of the Standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#2.1). The first quoted bullet describes pre-c++17 and I think leaves out the important bit that it must be the address of a _complete_ object that's described in the spec. Pre-c++17 specs did also include the explicit note that "_Addresses of array elements... are not acceptable template-arguments_".

Answer (score 2):

In C++17, from [[temp.arg.nontype]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#2):

> For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - a subobject,
> - [...]

Where a subobject is, from [[intro.object]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#def:subobject):

> Objects can contain other objects, called subobjects. A subobject can be a member subobject ([class.mem]), a base class subobject ([class.derived]), or an array element.

Using `&m` as a non-type template argument is fine - it points to an object. That object happens to be initialized from `n[1]`, but that doesn't matter.

On the other hand, `n+1` and `&n[1]` both point to an element of the array `n`, which is to say they both point to a subobject of `n`, and hence this is not allowed. `n+1` and `&m` are not related.

---

In [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.arg.nontype#1.3) and [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.arg.nontype#1.3), the wording was *inclusive* rather than *exclusive*, but the conclusion is the same:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
>
> - [...]
> - a constant expression ([expr.const]) that designates the address of a **complete object** with static storage duration and external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as [...]
> - [...]

A pointer to `m` is allowed, a pointer to `n[1]` is not.